# How do I create a picker that acts like a table view on Titanium Mobile?

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

How do I create a pickerRow that acts like a tableViewRow with the hasChild property? I wish to achieve the affect of the back button on the screen after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out you need to add the event on the picker itself and you can open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a TabGroup/TabView on the parent window, you can just add in a event listener in the pickerRow which you can call tabs.open(new_window), which will have the same effect.

So:

```
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({title: 'old win'});
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({title: 'new win'});
var tab = Ti.UI.createTab({window: win1});
tabGroup.tabs = [tab];
tabGroup.setActiveTab(0);

var pickerRow = Ti.UI.createPickerRow();
pickerRow.addEventListener('click', function(e) { tab.open(win2); });
```

But then again, I've never seen a pickerRow act as a window opener, so I'm going to say this isn't 100% supported by the Titanium SDK itself.